# I have a point that follows the mouse, how would I give it a limited turning rate?

Tags: java, methods, processing, trigonometry

I have a point that follows the mouse that I made in Processing.

```
void move() {
   double slope = (y - mouseY)/(x-mouseX);
    double atanSlope = atan(slope);
    if (slope < 0 && mouseY < y ) {
      x += cos(atanSlope)*(speed);
      y += sin(atanSlope)*(speed);
    } else if (slope >= 0 && mouseY < y) {
      x -= cos(atanSlope)*(speed);
      y -= sin(atanSlope)*(speed);
    } else if (slope > 0) {
      x += cos(atanSlope)*(speed);
      y += sin(atanSlope)*(speed);
    } else {
      x -= cos(atanSlope)*(speed);
      y -= sin(atanSlope)*(speed);
    }
}
```

How could I change this or add to this to make the point have a limited turning rate? What I had in mind would be similar to the missiles in this game. https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/181364872/
I don't know how I'd even start to limit the turning rate of the point. Any help would be appreciated.

(I tagged java too, because though this is in Processing, Processing is pretty much Java with built in methods at times.)

Comment: Keep track of the current direction, then calculate the direction to the mouse, adjust the current direction towards it (with limit), move towards current direction. Repeat.

Comment: Oh yeah, seems more obvious when you put it like that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to keep the object current direction. You can then use the cross product of the vector to the mouse, and the vector along the object's direction to find the angle it needs to turn to point to the mouse. You can then limit the turn and add the change to get the new direction.

```
double direction = ?; // the current direction of object in radians
double x = ?;  // the current position
double y = ?;
double maxTurn = ?; // Max turn speed in radians
double speed = ?;
void move() {
   double mvx = mouseX - x;   // get vector to mouse
   double mvy = mouseY - y;
   double dist = Math.sqrt(mvx * mvx + mvy * mvy);  // get length of vector
   if(dist > 0){  // must be a distance from mouse
       mvx /= dist;  // normalize vector
       mvy /= dist; 
       double ovx = Math.cos(direction); // get direction vector
       double ovx = Math.sin(direction);
       double angle = Math.asin(mvx * ovy - mvy * ovx); // get angle between vectors
       if(-mvy * ovy - mvx * ovx < 0){ // is moving away
          angle = Math.sign(angle) * Math.PI - angle;  // correct angle
       }
       // angle in radians is now in the range -PI to PI
       // limit turn angle to maxTurn
       if(angle < 0){
          if(angle < -maxTurn){
             angle = -maxTurn;
          }
       }else{
          if(angle > maxTurn){
             angle = maxTurn;
          }
       }
       direction += angle; // turn 
       // move along new direction
       x += Math.cos(direction) * speed;
       y += Math.sin(direction) * speed;
    }
}
```